# Remote database is not empty. Please create a new database or use heroku pg:reset

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I've been searching for an hours and no luck at all. I'm trying to push my local postgresql to heroku but this error occured. So this is my actual windows command:

```
heroku pg:push mydb postgresql-cubed-16465
```

After I enter it: `Remote database is not empty. Please create a new database or use heroku pg:reset`

Of course I just follow the instruction `heroku pg:reset` and is done. So I try to push it again, same result. Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Until now I cant push my postgre database to heroku. Anybody knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I follow the instruction in here and just remove `'` in the url
in this part `heroku pg:backups:restore 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/me/items/3H0q/mydb.dump' DATABASE_URL`

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export

Answer (score 0):

In my case, error message `psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused` was shown before this error. If you also can't reset database from the dashboard, this might be a problem with your internet connection and `heroku pg:reset` is not working.

After I use a stable connection, I was able to use `heroku pg:push`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I did these things:

1. Remove Procfile that was running migrate on push to production.
2. Fix up any migrations that were causing issues.
3. database.yml: set gssencmode to disable.

```
    # Database connection issues without gssencmode: disable
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59089991/ruby-2-6-5-and-postgresql-pg-gem-segmentation-fault
    
    default: &default
      adapter: postgresql
      encoding: unicode
      pool: 5
      checkout_timeout: <%= ENV['DB_TIMEOUT'] || 5 %>
      host: localhost
      username: postgres
    
    development:
      <<: *default
      database: my_app_development
      gssencmode: disable
    test:
      <<: *default
      database: my_app_test
      gssencmode: disable
```